# if any $k>0$ we have $|a-b|<k$, then $a = b $

Tags: complex-numbers

**Homework Problem**: Let $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$. Suppose that for all  $k \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $k > 0$ , we have $|a-b|<k$. Show  that $a = b$.

**Attempt** If $a \neq b$, then $a >b$ so $a-b>0$ since $|a-b|<k$ holds for any $k$, it must hold for $k = a - b > 0$ so $a-b < a-b$ which is a contradiction.

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Well, for one you have $a>b$ or $b>a$, but you can always throw in a "Without loss of generality" there

Comment: your $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$. In that case you cannot claim that $a \neq b \implies a>b$. Because Complex numbers are not ordered.

Comment: $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ , so what is the meaning of  $a>b$ ?

Comment: That can't be the correct statement of the problem.  Transcribe it exactly as given.

Comment: a and b are complex so you can't claim a > b.  But you can claim |a -b| > 0.  And then it is a valid proof.

Comment: The problem is rather with the problem statement formulation itself: "Let $a,b\in\Bbb C$." - OK, I take $a=1$, $b=i$. - "Let $k\in\Bbb R$ such that $k>0$ be arbitrary." - Ok, it seems I may take $k=\pi$ here. - "Suppose $|a-b|<k$." - No need to suppose here as indeed $|1-i||=\sqrt 2<\pi$. - "Show t$a0b$." - Sorry, you cannot show that $1=i$.

Comment: Yes, probably it should be something like, "Suppose that for all $k \in \mathbb{R}, k > 0, |a-b| < k$. Then..."

Comment: so you saying $a$ and $b$ be fixed? because in my statements i have quantifier at the begining? right? im so confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose  $a \neq b$, then  $|a-b|>0$, and so as  taking $k=|a-b| \in  \mathbb{R}$, we get  $|a-b|<|a-b|$ , contradiction.